# php-cs-fixer : keep brace on the same line of function declaration

Tags: php, php-cs-fixer

Php cs fixer is doing :

```
function foobar()
{
....
}
```

and I want:

```
function foobar() {
....
}
```

I can't see what is the config to keep braces on the same line in my config `.php_cs` file, nor on https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer. I'm using php-cs-fixerV2.

My config file: https://pastebin.com/v03v9Lb5

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have PSR-2 enabled, which requires the braces on the next line. From [the documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/3.0/doc/rules/index.rst) it looks like you can set `braces.position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs` to `same` (default would be `next`):

> - `position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs ('next', 'same')`: whether the opening brace should be placed on “next” or “same” line after classy constructs (non-anonymous classes, interfaces, traits, methods and non-lambda functions); defaults to 'next'

myconfig.php_cs:

```
    'braces' => array(
        'allow_single_line_closure' => true,
        'position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs' => 'same',
    ),
```

Comment: I'm also looking for the 1TBS mode for cs-fixer but I'm using Atom and the packages atom-beautify & php-cs-fixer. Does anyone know it this configuration can be put in the atom config file, the packages settings, or elsewhere ?

Comment: hello  @ponsfrilus. I never received notification for your coment sorry. you can add this in atom.
File > setting > packages > php-cs-fixer, then add your file's path in `PHP-CS-fixer config file path`

Comment: @user2203384 thanks, I've ended with a `.php_cs` in my repo, as this file is loaded by default in the php-cs-fixer in atom.

Comment: @scrowler thanks for your answer. The link is broken do you have a new one? I could not find a place explaining all available rules.

Comment: https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer/blob/3.0/doc/rules/index.rst this looks like the latest version

Answer (score 11):

The style you described here is called "[the one true brace style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Variant:_1TBS_(OTBS))" (abbreviated as 1TBS or OTBS).

As I get the exact same problem, I've finally ended here and while @Robbie answer helps, I still needed to search a lot.

So I finally get this `.php_cs` in my repository:

```
<?php

$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    //->exclude('somedir')
    //->notPath('src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Tests/fixtures/resources.php'
    ->in(__DIR__)
;

return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setRules([
        '@PSR2' => true,
        'strict_param' => false,
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'long'],
        'braces' => [
            'allow_single_line_closure' => true, 
            'position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs' => 'same'],
    ])
    ->setFinder($finder)
;
```

Some explainations (from the ([PHP-CS-Fixer README](https://github.com/FriendsOfPhp/PHP-CS-Fixer)):

- **array_syntax** to long means `array()` instead of `[]`. Whether to use the long or short array syntax; defaults to 'long';
- **allow_single_line_closure**: whether single line lambda notation should be allowed; defaults to false;
- **position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs**: whether the opening brace should be placed on "next" or "same" line after classy constructs (non-anonymous classes, interfaces, traits, methods and non-lambda functions); defaults to 'next'.

In IDE such Atom, the [php-cs-fixer plugin](https://atom.io/packages/php-cs-fixer) will search for the `.php_cs` config file in the root path of the current project. It's also possible to specify the path.

Last but not least, the website of [Michele Locati](https://github.com/mlocati/php-cs-fixer-configurator), [PHP CS Fixer configuration](https://mlocati.github.io/php-cs-fixer-configurator/) can really helps.

Comment: Very instructive thanks ! I use "short" array_syntax `[]`.
PHP CS Fixer configuration is very helpful : added to bookmark

Comment: Even this works. My god. Just to get this bid to figure out take me 20 mins. It is crazy.