# How to auto format PHP code curly braces to new lines in VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, php-cs-fixer

I'm currently using VS Code's latest version 1.41.1 (at the time of writing).

I've installed PHP CS Fixer to auto-format my code. However there's a behavious that I don't like. It always formats the code like this:

```
if (condition) {
    // code...
} else {
    // code
}
```

But this is not giving me good readability.

I'd like to achieve this:

```
if (condition)
{
    // code...
}
else
{
    // code
}
```

Is there any extentsion that supports this code formatting for PHP in VS Code? Or is there any option in PHP CS Fixer to skip formatting these curly brackets? Any other otpions?

Comment: let's say this is highly debatable. There is an option to pass a config file with rules to your extension. Maybe there is a [rule here](https://cs.symfony.com/) that would do what you are looking for.

Comment: Also, you don't need php-cs to format code in Visual Studio Code - just mark the code you want to format, CTRL+K + CTRL+F. But please just use PSR2 like everyone else ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on @Nicolas's comment I was able to make it work in 2 steps.

1. I had to create a file in the root of my project with a name of `.php_cs`
2. Add this block of code to the file:

   ```
   <?php

   return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
   ->setRules(array(
       'braces' => array(
           'position_after_anonymous_constructs' => 'next',
           'position_after_control_structures' => 'next',
       )
   ));
   ```

All done and works like a charm. Thanks for the help @Nicolas!

Comment: Glad i could help !

Answer (score 1):

Now days:

```
'control_structure_braces' => true,
'control_structure_continuation_position' => [
    'position' => 'next_line'
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for the same thing. I tried the (accepted) answer Radical_activity gave, but that didn't work for me. Found this another snippets here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883745/4638682

**Snippet:**

```
<?php

$finder = PhpCsFixer\Finder::create()
    //->exclude('somedir')
    //->notPath('src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Tests/fixtures/resources.php'
    ->in(__DIR__)
;

return PhpCsFixer\Config::create()
    ->setRules([
        '@PSR2' => true,
        'strict_param' => false,
        'array_syntax' => ['syntax' => 'long'],
        'braces' => [
            'allow_single_line_closure' => true, 
            'position_after_functions_and_oop_constructs' => 'same'],
    ])
    ->setFinder($finder)
;
```

From which you also need to create a `.php_cs` file in your repository.
That worked for me!